# Simple Office Typescript Example

Tags: typescript, office365, office-js

I've created a new Outlook Web Add-In project from Visual Studio, installed the Office TypeScript typings via npm.

I then changed the default example MessageRead.js to MessageRead.ts

in the function loadProps() we see this :
`let item = Office.context.mailbox.item;`

we then see the following line

```
$('#attachments').html(buildAttachmentsString(item.attachments));
```

but with the typescript intellisense the item class does not contain the attachments object.

Where am i going wrong? Could someone give a basic example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mailbox.item typings will only have members common to all item types. For message read item scenarios, try casting it like this: `(item as Office.MessageRead).attachments` to get message read members in intellisense. Hope this helps!

Comment: Office.MessageRead doesn't seem to have an object called attachments!?

Comment: Oh that's a bug in the typings file - we'll get that fixed. Thanks for bringing this up!

Comment: The typings file has been updated, you should be able to see the attachments object now.